# Finding the max value in an ArrayList of integers using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I don't have much on this... my assignment is to create a recursion method that will output the highest value in an ArrayList of integers.

```java
public static int maxValue(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        if (a.isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException ("Can't compute max of empty list.");
        if(a.size()==1){return a.get(0);}
        else {
            //not sure what to add here for the recursion
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is actually compare the first two values and remove the smallest one ( or one of them if equal) and set a base case of list size 1 like this:

```
public static int maxValue(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        if (a.isEmpty()) return -1;
        if (a.size() == 1) return a.get(0);
        if (a.get(0) <= a.get(1))
        {
            a.remove(0);
        } else
        {
            a.remove(1);
        }
        return maxValue(a);
    }
```

Comment: The solution is bad as it destroys the input. At least, it should use a copy of the input, although that would make it slow and memory hungry.

Comment: Yep i wanted to mention that, but based on what the OP wrote(starting code) it’s what the assignment needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.Math.*;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import static java.util.Objects.*;

public static int maxValue( List<Integer> list )
{
    if( isNull( list ) ) throw new IllegalArgumentException( "list is null." );
    if( list.isEmpty() ) throw new NoSuchElementException( "Can't compute max of empty list." );

    var size = list.size();
    var head = list.get( 0 );
    var retValue = size == 1 ? head : max( head, maxValue( list.sublist( 1, size ) ); 
    return retValue;
}
```

`List.subList()` does not return a copy of the (sub)list, but a new view on the underlying list.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirements permit, you could add a second parameter n, and pass the size of ArrayList.

```
   ...
   System.out.println(maxValue(arrlst, arrlst.size()));
   ...


public static int maxValue(ArrayList<Integer> a, int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return a.get(0);

    return Math.max(a.get(n - 1), maxValue(a, n - 1));
}
```